# Repurposing the .net type system - bad idea?

Tags: c#

I'm playing around with writing an item crafting system that I might want to put into a game someday. There are `Recipe`s which specify the ingredients they require and what they produce.

I wanted the recipes to be flexible, such that they only required a broad category of ingredients, not an exact one. For example, a recipe for a weapon blade might just say it requires a metal, not specifically steel. The recipes have to verify that the ingredients given are within the acceptable category. Some materials might belong to multiple categories.

Then I had a possibly brilliant, possibly insane idea. The .net type system already implements that! So for each material, I add a property of type `Type`, and use `IsAssignableFrom` to verify the ingredients' compatibility.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
public interface ItemType { }

public interface Material : ItemType { }

public interface Metal : Material { }

public interface Gold : Metal { }
public interface Silver : Metal { }
public interface Iron : Metal { }
public interface Steel : Metal { }

public interface Wood : Material { }
public interface Coal : Material { }
```

And so on. None of those are ever implemented. I'm just borrowing the built in type checking for my own purposes.

Is there anything necessarily wrong with this?

### edit: actual question

If I've been clear enough to explain what I'm *trying* to accomplish here, then what would you suggest is a good way to go about it, ignoring this whole type system abuse thing? Would you have also used this solution, or something else?

Second question, are there any pitfalls to watch out for in what I've done here?

Comment: Is this more of a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) question?

Comment: @paqogomez hmm... possibly. I'm more asking about the general concept of abusing the system in this way. If it gets deemed OT here then people will move it.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with this. No you don't have to do something else. And I don't know who can complain about this. I do have a hard time understanding what you expect to hear from SO. I am missing the point I'm afraid :).

Comment: Why are you so convinced that this is abusing the type system? There is nothing wrong with this approach. At all.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything necessarily wrong with this?

Yes, everything.

1. Classes and interfaces are meant to express behavior. There is no behavior in your code. Your code is not miscomunicating the intentions. Usually, when you see interface, you expect it to have some method and that method is called. That is not the case here.
2. It will become impossible to define the materials and recipes in some kind of configuration/resource file, like most normal games do. So you have to recompile every time you want to change the materials or recipe a little.
3. It will become problematic to create items/materials that are somehow related. For example, lets say there are multiple tools and each tool can be from different materials. In your case, you have to write down every combination. In ideal case, you can just run few nested for loops which create each combination.
4. You cannot parametrize the materials in any way without creating classes of them. For example, you might want different colors of wool. How would you do it? Create interface for each color? Or use some kind of enum as parameter. But you have to create class for that.

Better way would be simple Item class that has collection of tags. Even simple strings should be enough.